# "The specified network name is no longer available. (0x80070040)" error triggered from SoapCore Package

Tags: soapcore

Since we migrated our WCF services to .NET 5.0 using SoapCore package, we have been facing the following error:

```
Category: SoapCore.SoapEndpointMiddleware
EventId: 0

An error occurred processing the message

Exception: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: The client has disconnected
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070040): The specified network name is no longer available. (0x80070040)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IO.AsyncIOOperation.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadBody()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadAsync(Memory`1 memory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.StreamPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeReaderStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeReaderStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()
   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper.ReadBOMEncoding(Boolean notOutOfBand)
   at System.Xml.EncodingStreamWrapper..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.SetInput(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas, OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose onClose)
   at SoapCore.MessageEncoder.SoapMessageEncoder.ReadMessageAsync(Stream stream, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, String contentType)
   at SoapCore.MessageEncoder.SoapMessageEncoder.ReadMessageAsync(PipeReader pipeReader, Int32 maxSizeOfHeaders, String contentType)
   at SoapCore.SoapEndpointMiddleware`1.ProcessOperation(HttpContext httpContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

The occurance is very sporadic, but sometimes it happens in a large scale and heavily impacts the response time of our entire platform. Any insight into the resolution of this error will be very helpful.

We have been trying to replicate this error in our staging environment, but have not been successful so far.